# Keeping track of a variable in jupyter-notebook widgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget

I am working on an NLP model to answer 4 questions and I am trying to keep track of answered question by incrementing a global variable.

A question is answered if it contains 1 or more plausible terms.

I am using Jupyter notebook widgets with a dropdown where you can see paraphrases of questions (used for finding better answers). There are 4 widgets with 3 paraphrases each.

Clicking on a different paraphrase will make the NLP model run again and look for a different answer. And this is where I fail, because if you run all 3 paraphrases, the global var will get incremented 3 times. But the maximum answered quesions should be 4 and minimum should be 0.

```
controller_varx = 0 # global var for keeping track
```

My question is how do I stop the overwriting of the global variable if the question is answered?

I have done it for widget number 1, but I cannot figure a way for widgets 2 to 4. There is a huge amount of code, so I am trying to provide only the **scope** where I fail.

```
#this will work good every time you chose a different paraphrase 
#as it will set the controller_varx to 0 again
#code from within the widget
      
          if term_counter>= 3:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))


            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")

          elif term_counter== 2:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))

            controller_varx = 0
            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")

          elif term_counter== 1:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))

            controller_varx = 0
            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")

          else:
            print('\nNo good terms. Question unanswered.\n')

            controller_varx = 0
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")
```

Code from within widget 2. For this snippet, every time you choose a different paraphrase, if that paraphrase contains a plausible term, it will increment the controller_varx. So if I jump around from paraphrase 1 to 3, back to 1 and so on, I can end up with (any number)/4.

```
        if counter >= 3:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))
            print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -')

            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")

          elif counter == 2:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))
            print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -')

            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")

          elif counter == 1:
            print('\nAI Plausibility Score: ', plaus.score(term_counter))
            print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -')
            controller_varx = controller_varx + 1
            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")
          else:
            print('\nNo good terms. Question unanswered.\n')
            print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -')

            print("Answers: ", controller_varx, "/6")
```

Looking for inputs! Thank you if you read this far.